# AWS Lambda RequestHandler for a void output

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk-java-2.0

Consider a simple Lambda written in Java:

```
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context; 
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;

public class Hello implements RequestHandler<Integer, String>{
    public String handleRequest(int myCount, Context context) {
        return String.valueOf(myCount);
    }
}
```

The handler interface is defined as `RequestHandler<InputType, OutputType>`, but when my Lambda reacts to events and just does some side effects, is the output type unnecessary and I have to write something like this:

```
public class Hello implements RequestHandler<SNSEvent, Void>{
    public Void handleRequest(SNSEvent snsEvent, Context context) {
        ...
        return null;
    }
}
```

Which is annoying.

Is there an alternative to `RequestHandler` for a `void` handler?:

```
public class Hello implements EventHandler<SNSEvent>{
    public void handleEvent(SNSEvent snsEvent, Context context) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-programming-model-handler-types.html

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Sorry, I don't see any answer to my question under the link...

Comment: What exactly is your question @ttulka? You mean you don't want to return anything from your function, so rather than `Void` you want to use `void`? The link that Michael shared states that if your functions are invoked asynchronously, you can just use `void`. If they are invoked synchronously, however, they need to return a supported data type.

Comment: @Thales Yes, but `RequestHandler` forces me to use a return type, which is in the asynchronous case unnecessary. Or is there a different interface to use, with return type `void` (not `Void`) implicit?

Comment: Even the name `RequestHandler` doesn’t make much sense as it references *request-response*, a pattern for synchronous communication. But unfortunately I don't see any `EventHandler` or similar...

Comment: If I understood you correctly, this is not possible. You must always inform the return type in Java.

Comment: @Thales You're probably right. Sad. A `EventHandler` would be really handy...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't need to implement an interface for your Lambda entry point.  Your handler class can just be a POJO with a signature that fulfils the requirements [explained in the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-programming-model-handler-types.html).

For example:

```java
package example;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.SNSEvent;

public class Hello {
  public void handleEvent(SNSEvent event, Context context) {
    // Process the event
  }
}
```

In this case you should use `example.Hello::handleEvent` as the *handler* configuration.

See also [this example from the official docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/get-started-step4-optional.html):

```java
package example;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context; 
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.LambdaLogger;

public class Hello {
    public String myHandler(int myCount, Context context) {
        LambdaLogger logger = context.getLogger();
        logger.log("received : " + myCount);
        return String.valueOf(myCount);
    }
}
```